# How to modularly write JavaScript?

Tags: jquery, javascript

I am  a JavaScript developer and have most of the time faced a problem of arranging the code in a modular fashion so that it does not grow too big. I am aware of JQuery modules but I am not comfortable because as the project grows there is a huge chunk of code that populated the entire file. So is there any JS framework or some kind of solution for this so that I can easily modularize the code and is more readable and good for robust front end application. Please suggest me some frameworks or any other idea which would help in better structure of the code and also lets me build  a robust apps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest you to try the AMD style for javascript modularisation. You can use requirejs as module loader/dependency injection system and some MVC framework (backbone?) for complex application management. After understanding the basic concept you'll be amazed about how tidier javascript can be ;)

Comment: I am already using Spring as my MVC framework and would like to continue along with it. I wanted to know what is AMD style of JavaScript modularization?

Comment: You use Spring as MVC for backend code, but if you have a rich client-side application featuring lots of AJAX/Javascript interactions and you'd like to have UI state management (with html5 pushstate or hasbang for browser history) and keep it tidy you should definitely consider to use also a client side MVC. Look at backbone.js for more info about that: http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/
AMD instead is a way to asynchronously load and inject dependencies between javascript modules. Look at require.js here for more info: http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for that information. It would really solve the problem I am facing.

Answer (score 1):

[Backbone.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/) is an architectural app that helps to structure code. It can be used with other popular libraries such as jQuery or Zepto

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you try these:

- [require](http://requirejs.org/)
- [backbone](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/)

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is to look into a library that has a concept of modules at its core, like [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui).

Comment: I have already used these framework. I am wondering if I make my own module then how to reuse and import it etc

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you have a look at the [BarFoos Application Framework](https://github.com/jAndreas/BarFoos)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [terrificjs](http://www.terrifically.org/).

> TerrificJS is a neat, clever piece of code that allows you to
>   modularize your jQuery code by solely relying on the OOCSS naming
>   conventions.